# RPI 8MP CAMERA BOARD RASPBERRY PI CAMERA BOARD V2

Tags: camera, motion, picamera

I setup my raspberry Pi with a RPI 8MP CAMERA BOARD RASPBERRY PI CAMERA BOARD V2.

I'm using MotionEyesOs and Synology Surveillance Station.

I don't understand the camera, unless I'm wrong should support 1080P at 30FPS.

When I use 1080P settings, the view angle is limited to 50%. 
Is this expected? (7FPS in 1080P)

Also whatever the setting are, in my case 640/480 (which seems the only setting to see the full view) only run at 27FPS, but the video seems not smooth at all.

Comment: I think enabling the fast camera mode resolve most of my issue although I still have limited view field at 1080P

Comment: Motions quite an intensive piece of software. I think the camera can perform at 30fps 1080p but the pi is unlikely to process it quick enough with motion running. It's likely to be different with the new pi 4s but using a pi3b+ in the same setup as you described above I've found after some tweaking that 1600×1200 works for me at a frame rate of either 10 or 15fps.